# Delaying mounting of a component until an event happens ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am implementing a React app in which user can like or dislike a post. The same information is posted to server immediately. I have also used `redux` and `react-router` in my app. Below is the `SocialCount.js` component which handles likes and dislikes on a post.

```
import { post } from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SocialCount extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
        this.state={
            likes: props.likes,
            likeUpdated: false,
            dislikes: props.dislikes,
            dislikesUpdated: false,
            postId: props.postId,
            baseUrl: 'http://snaptok.herokuapp.com/'
        }

    handleLike=()=>{
        //A lot of calculation on state happenes here and post to server
    }

    handledislikes=()=>{
        //A lot of calculation on state happenes here and post to server
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.props)
        return(<>
        <li>
            <button>
            {this.state.likeUpdated?<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true" style={{fontSize: 'large'}} onClick={this.handleLike}></i>:<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true" style={{fontSize: 'large'}} onClick={this.handleLike}></i>}
              <span>{this.state.likes}</span>
            </button>
            <button>
            {this.state.dislikesUpdated?<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true" style={{fontSize: 'large'}} onClick={this.handledislikes}></i>:<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" aria-hidden="true" style={{fontSize: 'large'}} onClick={this.handledislikes}></i>}
              <span>{this.state.dislikes}</span>
            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>{this.props.length} Comments</a>
          </li>
          </>)
    }
}

export default SocialCount;
```

The props are coming from the parent which is connected to redux store. The reason I haven't connected SocialCount to store is that props cannot be changed, but state can.

Now lets come to the problem. On going to some other route in the app and then coming back to the SocialCount component retains old props that were passed to it before going to other route. It does not accepts new props from parent. So I see old number of likes and dislikes on the post, even though there are newer props available.

**What does it mean is that before the action is dispatched to the store, the constructor of SocialCount executes and initializes the state with the older props.**

So when new props come, state does not changes and hence I see old information of likes and dislikes. What I need is a method like `componentDidReceiveProps` to solve above problem. But it does not exist. So I need constructor not to execute until the newer props are available or to change state if newer props are detected.

Please help me to solve the problem by suggesting me some solution.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Don't update your state to match props. Instead just access the props directly in your render method.

i.e. `<span>{this.props.likes}</span>`

You may want this component to be entirely stateless

Comment: What you're saying is very much correct, but I need the all the operation on like and dislike button to happen in this state itself. We cannot change the props inside a child component. Thats why I have used state to handle these operations.

Comment: When a user likes or dislikes a post, the information is posted to the server in this component itself.

Comment: I see. This pattern is slightly awkward because you are tracking the application state in 2 places with no single source of truth. One is the state inside this component but also in redux. I'd recommending changing your pattern to update redux itself when the state changes.

Comment: This component can still make the update request if you want it to but it would read the data from redux